# How to use two workbooks and their worksheets altogether

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am using two workbooks at a time. The first workbook is the current workbook and the second will be opened while programming execution. I have made the global objects of the workbooks and worksheets. I'm having issues with using the worksheets simultaneously. The error is `ERROR: object variable or with block variable, not set`. I have mentioned the error in the comment in the second subroutine.

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook

Dim WKS As Worksheet
Dim WKS2 As Worksheet

Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    WB.Activate

    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fd.Title = "Provide a title here."
    fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
    If fd.Show() = True Then
        strFile = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
        Set WSK2 = WB2.Sheets("Schweitzer Analysis")
        CalculateGrades
    Else
        MsgBox ("No file selected")
    End If
End Sub

Sub CalculateGrades()
    ' first clear the contents where grades results can appear
    clearGradesContents

    Dim index As Integer ' for current sheet
    Dim index2 As Integer ' for student sheet
    Dim countCorrect As Integer ' to count no of correct answers

    index = 2
    index = 8
    countCorrect = 0

    ' this first error here
    ' ERROR: object variable or with block variable not set
    Set WKS = WB.ActiveSheet

    Do While index <= 21
        ' the SECOND error shows here
        If WKS.Cells(index, 2) = WKS2.Cells(index2, 3) Then
            Count = Count + 1
        Else
            WKS.Cells(index, 5) = WKS2.Cells(index2, 3)
        End If

        If WKS.Cells(index, 3) = WKS2.Cells(index2, 4) Then
            Count = Count + 1
        Else
            WKS.Cells(index, 6) = WKS2.Cells(index2, 4)
        End If

        index2 = index2 + 1
        index = index + 1
    Loop

End Sub


Sub clearGradesContents()
    Range("E2:F21").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("I2:I3").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: sorry for the previous answer, I hadn't seen your global declarations on top and I was sure it was because you hadn't declare it.

I think the issue is the following:

```
[...]
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
WB.Activate '<-- WB is the active workbook now
[...]
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(strFile) '<-- WB2 is the active workbook now!
Set WSK2 = WB2.Sheets("Schweitzer Analysis")
CalculateGrades '<-- going to next macro
[...]
Set WKS = WB.ActiveSheet '<-- ERROR: WB2 is the active workbook. WB can't have an active sheet if it's not the active workbook
```

Then of course, being `WKS` not correctly set, you can't execute this:

```
If WKS.Cells(index, 2) = WKS2.Cells(index2, 3) Then
```

I have no way to test it now, but I think that should be the issue.
To solve it,

**If you really need WKS to be the ActiveSheet**

```
Dim activeSheetName As String
...
Sub Button1Click()
    ...
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    WB.Activate
    activeSheetName = WB.ActiveSheet.Name
    ...
End Sub
Sub CalculateGrades()
    ...
    Set WKS = WB.Sheets(activeSheetName)
    ...
```

**If you already know the name of the sheet you need**

Just write:

```
Set WKS = WB.Sheets("your sheet")
```

instead of

```
Set WKS = WB.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I didn't understand it clearly. I have made the objects globally, then how can they be destroyed in a macro? And the second thing, what you have mentioned in your code, as I have mentioned in my code, so what's the change?

Comment: @SHEIKH you shouldn't change it in your answer (otherwise other users reading it will not see the "Question" + "Answer" logic). 

Regarding your first question, you can destroy an unused object with `Set WB = Nothing` when you stop using it. 

Regarding your second question, I admit I didn't get what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, in your solution, I don't see anything new which is different than my code. Please mention clearly what I have to change in my code.

Comment: @SHEIKH were the global declaration already there in your original question?? I might be a bit tired but I was sure I hadn't seen them when I first wrote my answer. Sorry about that. Could you please add the line `Debug.Print TypeName(WB)` right before the line `Set WKS = WB.ActiveSheet` where you get the error, execute the code and tell me what you see in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @SHEIKH I've modified my answer. I'm sorry for the first one, I really did not see you were already declaring your variables globally.

Comment: Now same error `' ERROR: object variable or with block variable not set `is showing on the `while loop` first statement that is `If WKS.Cells(index, 2) = WKS2.Cells(index2, 3) Then`

Comment: You did not set index2. You set index = 2 and index = 8.